# How to regenerate DIV when executing the event again with filesInput?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener, kill

currently working on an administration panel, I want for the user a preview of the image that is about to send after adding a file with an html input element.
Currently the script works, but if you decide to choose a new file with the input again ( the div does not regenerate but duplicates with the new image, leaving the old one still visible.

So I would like the div and the preview to regenerate when we choose an image again with input.

But the question is, how can I do this ?

Thank you all very much in advance for your advice / solutions.
Hope I am understandable, I am a novice and I explain this in my words.

I also send you my greetings from France.

***HTML***

```
<div id="result">

<input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" name="image"/>
```

***Javascript***

```
window.onload = function() {
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("image");
    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        var output = document.getElementById("result");
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.type.match('image'))
                continue;
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = "<div class=\"card\" style=\"max-width: 10rem;\"> <img class='card-img-top' src='" + picFile.result + "'" + "title='" + picFile.name + "'/> <div class=\"card-body rgba-black-light p-2\" style=\"text-align:center;\">Nouvelle image </div></div>  ";
                output.insertBefore(div, null);

            });
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OUTPUT.innerHTML = ""
```

after the output declaration, this set the content of the div "result" to "" (empty)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to regenerate image, you can remove the previous image.

I gave a id to div where image inside and remove it before where you added image.

Here is the snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("image");
    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        var output = document.getElementById("result");
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.type.match('image'))
                continue;
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
                var picFile = event.target;
                var div = document.createElement("div");
              
              var imageDiv = document.getElementById("imageDiv");//get div element
              if(imageDiv!=null){//check div element 
                imageDiv.remove();}//remove the previous div
                div.innerHTML = "<div class=\"card\" style=\"max-width: 10rem;\" id='imageDiv'> <img class='card-img-top' src='" + picFile.result + "'" + "title='" + picFile.name + "'/> <div class=\"card-body rgba-black-light p-2\" style=\"text-align:center;\">Nouvelle image </div></div>  ";
                output.insertBefore(div, null);

            });
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }})}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">

<input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" name="image"/>
```